# Bitwise operators code

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to understand the bitwise and the shift operators.
I wrote a simple code to show me the bits in a short type.

```
    class Shift {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        short b = 16384;

        for (int t = 32768; t > 0; t = t/2) {
            if ((b&t) !=0) System.out.print("1 ");
            else System.out.print ("0 ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        b = b+2;
        for (long t = 2147483648; t > 0; t = t/2) {
            if ((b&t) != 0) System.out.print ("1 ");
            else System.out.print ("0 ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
C:\>javac Shift.java
Shift.java:11: error: integer number too large: 2147483648
                for (long t = 2147483648; t > 0; t = t/2) {
                              ^
1 error
```

I don't understand why a long type can't hold the value 2147483648.

### Thank you for your help.

Thank you for your answers.
I changed the code:

```
    class Shift {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        short b = 16384;

        for (int t = 32768; t > 0; t = t/2) {
            if ((b&t) !=0) System.out.print("1 ");
            else System.out.print ("0 ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        b = (short)(b+2);
        for (long t = 2147483648L; t > 0; t = t/2) {
            if ((b&t) != 0) System.out.print ("1 ");
            else System.out.print ("0 ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And the output is now:

```
C:\>java Shift
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Why is the output of the second "for" an integer?

Comment: `long t = 2147483648l`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`JLS #3.10.1. Integer Literals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-IntegerLiteral),

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

Hence

```
long t = 2147483648
```

Should be

```
long t = 2147483648L
```

Where `L` literal tells the compiler that it's a long value. Otherwise by default compiler treats that as a `int`  value.

Comment: Thank you.
I changed it and it worked.
But the output is:
C:\>java Shift
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
Why is the output of the second line a int?

Answer (score 2):

`2147483648` is an `int` literal, and it's too large for an `int`. Change it to `2147483648L` for a `long` literal.